# PUGS is a rectangle. If the equation of PU is $y=\frac{2}{3x} + 4$. What is the slope of SP?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I don't get the answer to this problem, can somebody please tell me what the answer is.

Comment: The line segments $SP$ and $PU$ are perpendicular (why?). Can you relate the slopes of perpendicular lines?

Comment: [First hit on Google](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/slope2.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to re-draw the rectangle so that it is slanted. Do you mean the equation of PU is y=2/3x+4? That means the slope is 2/3. Since SP is at a right angle to PU (it's a rectangle so it has to be), then it's slope is the negative reciprocal of that. That would be -3/2 (flip the fraction and multiply by -1), so the answer is C. Hope this helps.

Comment: Try drawing it on graph paper with PU going up 2 and over 3, and it will be easier to visualize.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Suppose some extension of a line segment has equation $y=mx+b$. Then any line that is perpendicular to this line (in other words, at a $90$ degree angle with it), has slope $-\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: Okay, I think its C, Is it?

Comment: Yes, the correct answer is C because this is the negative reciprocal of $\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is C, assuming that the equation of PU is $y = \frac{2}{3}x+4$.

Comment: How do you solve it?  I don't get it.

Comment: It is the negative reciprocal of 2/3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome.